# Referencing Firefox event objects via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom-events, google-maps-api-2

I am still using Google maps v2, and I am having trouble getting the event object from Firefox when a google event fires. Ultimately, I need the event object so that I can retrieve information about keys being pressed when the click event of a particular overlay fires. Here is some code:

```
GEvent.addListener(polys[i], "click", function(e) {
    var evtObj = window.event? event : e;
    for (var i=0; i<polys.length; i++) {
        if ( this == polys[i] ) {
            if (evtObj.ctrlKey) {
                map.closeInfoWindow();
                clickCounty(labels[i]);
            }
            other stuff to happen....
        }
});
```

This works fine in IE and Chrome. The variable `e` passed into the function is the lat/long of the `click` event. So how would I reference the Firefox event object rather than the Google event lat/long..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no great way to do this. I recommend binding an event to the DOM version of the `polys[i]` object (usually referenced in something like `polys[i].Zk`) instead of using `GEvent.addListener`. It may be easier to use the rendered object and attach to that after the map has loaded, rather than looking for it in `polys[i].Zk`.

For example, if your object is an img marker, you could do something like this (using jQuery for shorthand, even though I know you haven't tagged with jQuery):

```
$('#map-box').on('click', 'img', function(evtObj) {
  for (var i=0; i<polys.length; i++) {
    if ( this == polys[i].Zk ) {
      if (evtObj.ctrlKey) {
        map.closeInfoWindow();
        clickCounty(labels[i]);
      }
      other stuff to happen....
    }
  ...
});
```

Of course, you'd probably want to be a little more granular in your selection, and you lose the lat/lon normally passed in, but you can access those elsewhere if you really need them (e.g. you could keep the `addListener` binding and cache the coordinates to use across bindings).